# Symfony Route not found

Tags: php, symfony

I'm really new with symfony, and I have strange problem.
I have a default controller, which looks like:

- Both Controllers located:

**src/AppBundle/Controller/**

- Names:

**DefaultController.php**
and
**CmsController.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        die('Homepage');
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to create new one:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CmsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/cms")
     */
    public function cmsAction(Request $request)
    {
        die('Cms Page');
    }
}
```

Routing file looks like:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

When I try to go for www.domainname.com - default controller shows "Homepage" - as it should.
When I try to go for www.domainname.com/cms - it gives error 404.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Are you running in development mode?  If not, did you clear the cache?

Comment: @Cerad It is in production mode an hosted in shared hosting.How could I try clearing cache without terminal?

Comment: That was cache... Thank you!

Comment: *Never* develop in prod environment

Comment: Please advise for my knowledge, why it is bad to develop in prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probelm was simply with cache. Clearing it solved the problem.